# django modelform how to know input type is checkbook?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-2.x

My modelform is a dynamically generated modelform,I want to know the type of is_true in the modelForm. The type of the input tag is the checkbook type.
If I know the  type=‘checkbox’ of the is_true field, add a class attr to him separately.
The default type='checkbox’ interface is too ugly

models

```
class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    用户表
    """
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='姓名')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='邮箱', unique=True)
    is_true = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='是否超级用户')
```

views

```
class ModelFormDemo(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = self.model
        if self.list_editable:
            fields = self.list_editable
        else:
            fields = '__all__'

    excluded = self.excluded

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelFormDemo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def add_view(self, request):

    form = ModelFormDemo()

    if request.method == "POST":
        res_dict = {'status': 1, 'msg': 'success'}
        form = ModelFormDemo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
        else:
            res_dict['msg'] = form.errors
            res_dict['status'] = 2
        return JsonResponse(res_dict)
    return render(request, "xadmin/add_view.html", locals())
```

html

```
<form class="layui-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.name == 'employee' %}
            <input type="hidden" name="employee" value="{{ user.id }}">
        {% else %}
            <div class="layui-form-item">
                <label class="layui-form-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="layui-input-inline">
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="layui-form-item">
        <div class="layui-input-block">
            <input type="button" class="layui-btn" lay-filter="add" lay-submit="" value="add">
            </input>

            <button type="reset" class="layui-btn layui-btn-primary">reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Widget.attrs` arg in your form `__init__` method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs